# Symfony 3 debug http requests with xdebug and server:start like I do with apache

Tags: xdebug, symfony-3.1

Fellows I want after I use the following command to start the symfony's webserver:

> php bin/console server:start

When I perform any request with curl such as:

> curl -X POST -d "name=Dimitrios Desyllas" -d "email=dddesillas@freemail.gr" -d "schools[]=1" -d "schools[]=2"  http://localhost:8000/add/member?XDEBUG_SESSION_START

To be able to use my editor's debug ui in order to debug my application.

How can I do that?